# If statement inside a loop filling a table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I'm using jQuery to fill in a timetable information, the information is supplied in a JSON format. This is the loop that I'm using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < r.events.length; i++) {
  myvar = r.events[i].slot;
  $("#" + myvar).text( r.desc + r.events[i].type + r.events[i].rooms +
                       r.events[i].id + r.events[i].duration );
```

So I need to insert an `if` statement into the loop that if the duration of the event equals 2 then the loop fills the cell AND cell +1. (The cells are named: `wed09`, `wed10`, `wed11`, `wed12`, `wed13`, `wed14`, `wed15`, `wed16`, `thu09`, `thu10` and so on.)

How would I code this?

Many thanks

Comment: can you give us a quick jsfiddle.net starting point. Stub the data for r.

Comment: jsfiddle.net:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4sn8/

Comment: quick question. so, if lets say on wed16, we get an event duration of 2. What happens? Is a new TD created or since  it doesn't go beyond '16', it doesn't get the +1 treatment?

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to go out of 16. The events will end at max 16. Sorry this took so long, I would be very grateful if I could still get your help :)

Comment: What do you mean with cell+1 ? Because `r.events` has already the name of the cell it needs to fill, you don't need to iterate on the cells...

Comment: Events have either 1, 2 or 3 in duration (hours). And the loop fills 3 hour and 2 hour events only in one slot (so they appear that they only last one hour). Have a look at  jsfiddle.net/V4sn8. I need an if statement like so: If duration (of a particular event) = 2 then put the description into the cell asigned (for example wed09) and one after wed09 so wed10. Does this make sense? If duration=3 then fill the cell asigned and two more after that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to have a TimeTable class like this:

```
var TimeTable = function(currentCell) {
    var days = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"];
    var hours = ["09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"];
    var currentDay = days.indexOf(currentCell.substring(0,3));
    var currentHour = hours.indexOf(currentCell.substring(3));
    // nextCell: updates the values on the TimeTable object
    var nextCell = function () {
        var lastDay = days.length - 1;
        if (currentHour === hours.length - 1) {
            currentHour = 0;
            currentDay++;
        } else {
            currentHour++;
        }
    }
    // getNextCell: gets the current Cell and increments the next cell
    getNextCell = function () {
        var currentCell = days[currentDay] + hours[currentHour];
        nextCell();
        return currentCell;
    }
    // fill: fills (duration) times the adjacent cells
    // input duration: the duration of the event ( > 0 )
    // input text: the text that needs to be filled into each cell 
    this.fill = function (duration, text) {
        for (var i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            $("#" + getNextCell()).text(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you talked about the duration which could be 2 or higher, I used a for loop instead of an if in the `fill` method, so it would fill 3 cells if duration = 3, etc.

Finally, you need to replace your `for` loop like this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < r.events.length; i++) {
            var timeTable = new TimeTable(r.events[i].slot);
            text = r.desc + '\n' + r.events[i].type + '\n' + r.events[i].rooms + '\n' + r.events[i].id + r.events[i].duration;
            timeTable.fill(r.events[i].duration, text);
        }
```

The code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raviolicode/3V5w4/)